# Android image effect like emboss, oilpaint etc

Tags: android, image, effect

Hi I am currently working on small android app that use the different image effect like sepia, charcoal, sketch, monochrome,Oil paint, Emboss, Negate . I didn't understand how to achieve those effect in my app. If any one did coding for those effect plz share. and give some ideas to achieve those effect. Thanks in advance..:-)

Comment: I found a link which showing some image-processing effects. [check this link](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/), it may help you a little bit.

Comment: See my answer here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662123/photo-editing-on-phonegap-android

Answer (score 1):

You could use color matrix for this purpose such as code to negate image is as follow;

```
        public Bitmap negative(Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            float[] negative_colour_matrix={-1, 0, 0, 0,255,
                                             0,-1, 0, 0,255,
                                             0, 0,-1, 0,255,
                                             0, 0, 0,1,0};
            ColorMatrix colorMatrix=new ColorMatrix(negative_colour_matrix);
            return get_bitmap_from_color_matrix(colorMatrix,bitmap);
        }
        public Bitmap get_bitmap_from_color_matrix(ColorMatrix colorMatrix,Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            Bitmap ret=Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight(),bitmap.getConfig());
            Canvas canvas=new Canvas(ret);
            Paint paint=new Paint();
            paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix));
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,0,0,paint);
            return ret;
        }
```

It will give the negative image;

[image]